# CSS Grid auto-fill with max-content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 4 divs, lets call them a,b,c,d. Their heights and widths can change (for example, during translation), but the height of a and b will always be equal (they are 1 row each). I want to arrange them in two columns, with a and c in the left column, b and d in the right column (the widths of the columns are NOT necessarily equal), but when this would cause overflow, I want them to fold into one column, ordered a-b-c-d top-to bottom. The closest I got was this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background: red;">A</div>
  <div style="width: 120px; height: 20px; background: yellow;">B</div>
  <div style="width: 80px; height: 40px; background: green;">C</div>
  <div style="width: 130px; height: 60px; background: blue;">D</div>
</div>
```

Changing the number in the repeat to 1 produces the expected arrangement, but `repeat(auto-fill, max-content)` doesn't work, as automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined with intrinsic or flexible sizes (such as `max-content`, `min-content`, `auto`). Is there any way to achieve this?